# What are reading comprehension tools that can generate or suggest plainer language?

Tags: word-choice, grammar, reading, language-formation

I'm looking for ways to simplify a document for better comprehension after I have already gone through an editing process myself. It could include suggestions easier synonyms, grammar optimization (adding commas or rearranging sentences), or plain language in general. I've only found a few resources:

[Okapi](http://www.lefthandlogic.com/htmdocs/tools/okapi/okapi.php)
This highlights difficult words according word whitelist from Spache (Grade 1-3) and Dale-Chall (Grade 4 & up). It can only handle 200 words at a time.

Microsoft Word can provide Flesch-Kincaid Reading Ease score (0-100) and Reading Level (about school grade) after doing a SpellCheck if you have enabled this option in preferences.

I know that software, algorithms, and automation will never quite accomplish everything, like finding for example:

- How complex the ideas are
- Whether or not the content is in a logical order
- Whether the vocabulary is appropriate for the audience
- Whether there is a gender, class or cultural bias
- Whether the design is attractive and helps or hinders the reader
- Whether the material appears in a form and type style that is easy or hard to read
  [ from http://plainlanguage.com/newreadability.html ]

But are there tools other than those in Microsoft Word, a thesaurus, or the OKAPI tool that would help improve a text document?