# How can you estimate how many people know a word?

Tags: vocabulary, statistics

There are already plenty of sites that tell you the relative frequency of a word in various corpuses, but how can you use that number to find an estimate of what % of native English speakers know that word?

I think I remember using a site that would give you a rough estimate, i.e. "most", "some", or "few people know this word".  Does anybody know what that site is?  Does anybody know of a site that is more precise?

Comment: Hello Zaz, and Welcome to EL&U. This does not look like a question about English usage. Questions about resources are probably better received on Meta.

Comment: @Cascabel: Why hide the question away on Meta? "Meta is meant to provide support for the operation of this site and we cannot let it morph into an alternative type of subject Q&A." - [Robert Cartaino♦](https://latin.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103/should-we-make-a-canonical-resources-question/142#142) If you insist on considering this question off-topic on the main site (why, I don't know; it seems interesting and relevant to English usage to me) Meta is also no place for it.

Comment: This question does not appear to be about English language and usage within the scope defined in the help center.

Comment: @sumelic I agree that it is potentially an interesting question. In fact, I would like to address it. However, as long as I have been contributing here I have seen requests for resources being shunted off to Meta, or closed for off-topic.  If this is on-topic according to the scope, then I will throw my support behind it and withdraw my comment. But I think we need clarification about the appropriacy of this type of post. [BTW, I have not voted to close.]

Comment: @Cascabel: You are right that people migrate these kind of questions to Meta in practice. However, [I think that this is a mistake](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9443/what-is-the-point-of-migrating-all-resource-requests-to-meta). To be clear, this is my own viewpoint (although influenced by the cited post by Robert Cartaino) and not the current consensus of high-rep users on this site. I hope to convince people to stop treating interesting questions about resources this way.

Comment: In my opinion, this is not a resource question, but a process question.  The question is: “How does one estimate how many people know a word.” To me, this falls in the category of *Usage*.  This debate on whether it is on/off topic belongs on Meta.

Comment: I think this could be considered a lexicography question (which are allowed, according to [this meta post](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10154/191178)), as this is information that is included in some dictionaries, such as [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/windward?s=t) and OED.com.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think that this measurement of proportion knowing word X can be done directly.

An alternative would be to use the Flesch-Kincaid index, which gives a readability by grade level. This tool takes into account the difficult of the vocabulary and length of the sentence, among others.

As your ultimate goal is unclear, perhaps these questions and answers at this site might get you started.

- Using the online tool to rate a difficult sentence from philosophy: https://english.stackexchange.com/a/364259/3306
- See the *Pearson's Level 6 list* in a comment at [English books reading complexity ratings](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/236973/3306)
- Using the Okapi tool: [What are reading comprehesion tools that can generate or suggest plainer language?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/83328/3306)

Comment: It would be nice to have a source that would rank a word according to the likelihood that X percent of some population (perhaps native speakers educated a high school or above, for example) are familiar with the word (perhaps outside of technical or specialist vocabulary).

Comment: I think you are looking for a Probability Density Function on a given word. But there are so many questions! What is the PDF based on? The world population? All teenage English speakers plus all adults? the PDF is quite different for a 16 year old vs a 24 year old. And when you want someone to be familiar with a word, do you want them to be able to pronounce it? To recognize it in a sentence? Or to define it? And how well should they define it? Are you familiar with "pied"? Many English speakers are familiar with the legend of the Pied Piper. But few adults know what "pied" means.